# Projection to cohomology

Tags: homology-cohomology

I have a differential graded algebra $(A,d)$ and $H^*$ be a graded ring.

Let $Z^*=Ker(d)$ and $\alpha:H^*(A)->Z^*$ be a right inverse for the **projection to cohomology**.

I have the following questions:

1.What is $Z^*$?

(usually with * in the paper the author denotes complexes, like $H^*$, but here...).

2.What is this projection?

Thanks!

Comment: Please use mathjax for the mathematical terms.

Comment: $Z^*=\ker d$ as you wrote. What is wrong with that ? With the zero differential it is a complex. As for the projection $H^*=Z^*/B^*$ (where $B^*=\operatorname{Im}d$), so the projection is just the canonical map $Z^*\to H^*$.